# Jquery questions about callback of ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

See the following code snippet:

```
$("#someid").autocomplete({
    source: function (req, resp) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/someapi", 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: req.someid },
            beforeSend : function()
            {

            },
            success: function (data) {
                resp($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: "<div class='result'>" + item.name + "</div>",
                        value: item.Name,
                        emailName: item.EmailName
                    };
                }));
            }
            }
        });
    });
```

My questions are listed below:

1. the source of ajax call is a function - ***function(req, resp)*** - does jQuery accept a function with two parameters as source data provider? Is this by default?
2. Can any one explain the function after ***success:***? Basically, I could get that it uses the data from ajax response; map each data to one item with some css decoration. But my question is: what's the goal of wrapping $.map with ***resp***?
3. We can see that there're a couple of callbacks in this code snippet. However, since I'm pretty new to jQuery, I wonder how to determine how many parameters to pass into each callback, say after **source:** we can have a callback with two parameters; after $.map, we can have another callback with only one parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes we can pass multiple parameters, It depends upon event which is being called & how it defined.
2. Success is callback for Ajax being called for autocomplete feature.
3. You should read documentation of such functions on jQuery website.

**[jQuery API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/)**

Comment: Thanks, Apul. Do you think the documentation is the only way to go?

Comment: It will help you to better understand the functions of jQuery. However, you should read jQuery code to know how are they defining events & their default callbacks.